# Adding new child to Firebase database

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

[image: database]

Trying to add a profile image string to new child. 
I tried setvalue but it changes all the childs in uid to only profileimage.

```
if let data = try? Data.init(contentsOf: dataurl!){
    let image: UIImage = UIImage(data: data)!
    self.userProfileImage.image = image
    self.userProfileImage.reloadInputViews()
    self.activityloading.stopAnimating()
    // Test Database Ref
    let stringURL = dataurl?.absoluteString

    let databaseRef = Database.database().reference().child("users").child(currentID!)
    let userImageElement: [String: Any] = ["profileimage" : stringURL!]
    databaseRef.observe(.childAdded, with: { (DataSnapshot) in
        var dictionary = DataSnapshot.value as! [String : Any]
        dictionary = userImageElement
    })
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace your `databaseRef.observe(.childAdded, with:{})` with `databaseRef.updateChildValues(userImageElement)` .